# Ruby File.each(e) block binds `self` to File not the instance?

Tags: ruby

Just teaching myself some Ruby, and wrote a little mixin to try out adding behaviors to File.  Would like to write the shortest bit of code, specifically `myFn`:

```
module MyMixin
  def fnSelf(filename)
      File.new(filename).each { |line| puts "#{self.lineno}: #{line}" }
  end

  def fnLexcial(filename)
      f = File.new(filename)
      f.each { |line| puts "#{f.lineno}: #{line}" }
  end
end

class File
    extend MyMixin
end
```

Certainly `fnLexical` works, given the lexical scoping on `f`, but I would have expected (coming from the perspective of a Smalltalk programmer) that `self` in `fnSelf` would have been bound to the instance of File upon which `.each` was called, but instead it is bound to `File` (the class).

Other iterators on other classes work as I would expect, such as:

```
module MyArrayMixin
  def fnSelf()
    self.each { |e| puts "#{self} --- #{e}" }
  end
end

class Array
  include MyArrayMixin
end

[1,2,3,4,5].fnSelf
```

... which works as I would intuitively expect.

Now, I realize that I'm `extend`ing `File` but `include`ing into `Array`, but that implies that `self` is not bound dynamically at runtime inside of each block, which is again not what I would have expected.  I must be missing some bit of intuitive understanding about Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference between `extend` and `include` is that:

- `include` adds behaviour to *instances* of the class.
- `extend` adds behaviour the *the class itself*.

Remember that in ruby - like smalltalk - (almost) *everything* is an object; `File` is an instance of [`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html).

Hopefully this explains why `self == File` in your first method: because the object you are defining the method on literally is the class (and object): `File`.

Now then, how could one go about writing this method in a one-liner that works?

```
module MyMixin
  def fnSelf(filename)
      File.new(filename).each { |line| puts "#{self.lineno}: #{line}" }
  end
end
```

Firstly, it's worth mentioning a couple of (very well conformed to) [ruby styleguide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) points: `snake_case` method names, and 2-space tabs.

The easiest way to implement this would be to use [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) rather than falling back to the `lineno` method:

```
module MyMixin
  def fn_self(filename)
    File.new(filename).each_with_index { |line, idx| puts "#{idx + 1}: #{line}" }
  end
end
```

However, as a purely academic exercise here, if you want to achieve this result by use of a closure then you can ["`tap` into"](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-tap) the object like so:

```
module MyMixin
  def fn_self(filename)
    File.new(filename).tap { |file| file.each { |line| puts "#{file.lineno}: #{line}" } }
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you have indeed corrected my thinking, but to be (perhaps overly) precise, it's not merely the fact that the method (`fnSelf` in my case) is defined as a class method (defined on `File`), but that the closure created by the block (in `{...}`) binds `self` inside the block to the (implicit) lexical/outer value of `self`, and since the closure is created in the context of a class method, `self` is of course `File`.   This is consistent with my (a bit rusty) Smalltalk.  Correct me if I'm still wrong...

Comment: And thanks for the other examples - they help a lot, and are interesting.  I particularly like the last with the use of `.tap`.

Comment: @eggo *"the closure [...] binds `self` inside the block to the (implicit) lexical/outer value of `self`*" -- Yes, that's correct. Also worth highlighting, if you're interested in reading more, is [`BasicObject#instance_exec`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec). This is powerful meta-programming method for [changing the value of `self`](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/03/12/understanding-instance-exec-in-ruby.html) within a closure.